# Draw a circle shape child node which center is parent center texture

Tags: macos, sprite-kit

I'm having problems drawing a child node (exactly a circle) and want to draw it taking as center the center of the parent node. I've not reach to draw the shape into the parent texture area. I want to draw the circle as the vision range of the character.

Here an image as example :
[image: sample image]

I've made other question about node position like [this] but the answer doesn't work here. I tried with child `position (0.5, 0.5)` expecting to draw the shape in center of parent node. I tried too with `-parentnode.size.width/2` or `-parentnode.size.width` but also didn't work.[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362927/different-node-position-in-screen-and-value)

Here is the code to draw the circle:

```
+(SKShapeNode *) dibujarCirculo:(NSInteger) radio
{
    CGRect box = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, radio, radio);
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, box);

    SKShapeNode *circle = [SKShapeNode node];
    circle.path = path;
    CGPathRelease(path);
    circle.alpha = 0.5;
    circle.fillColor = [SKColor greenColor];
    circle.lineWidth = 0.0f;

    return circle;
}
```

And here the code to assign the circle to the parent node:

```
-(void) dibujarCirculoVision
{
    SKShapeNode *vision = [punto dibujarCirculo:krangoDisparoPistola];
    vision.zPosition = 1;
    vision.name = @"vision";
    vision.alpha = 0.3f;
//  vision.position = CGPointMake(-cobra.size.width-krangoDisparoPistola, -cobra.size.height-krangoDisparoPistola);
    vision.position = CGPointMake(-0.5, -0.5);

    [cobra addChild:vision];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the draw in rect try this to draw a circle:

```
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, circleCenter.x, circleCenter.y, radius, 0, M_PI*2, NO);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
```